Split air conditioner's internal unit dripping water
The internal unit of this split air conditioner drips water from inside the air duct (see video below). Note that there are two more identical air conditioners in the same apartment and one larger one from the same brand and none of the three exhibit this behavior.
Water starts dripping 40-60 minutes after the unit has started and the amount of water dripping depends on how humid the day is. The water will typically stop dripping after 20-30 minutes, I suppose because the room humidity at that point is low.
I suspected a clogged condensate line but I brought a repairman who cleaned it and then poured about one liter of water and said that it is draining immediately without any leak.
What could be the issue here? I don't know how to proceed.


An air conditioner will condense water out of the air, and provision just be made to drain it. Window ACs just dump it outside, and must be mounted so the water will flow in that direction. Split designs will need some kind of drain from the cool side, which may mean into a manually emptied catch bucket or via a tube to a drain or outside. The latter may need a pump to assist, depending on how the tubing is routed.
Note that household dehumidifiers have the same issue and must apply the same solutions, though many of them have a catch basin file signed in, with a float switch that turns them off if that is approaching full so they don't overflow.
Three of my mini-split heads just drain into a tube through the wall, by gravity. The other two are not on outside walls and need pumps to get the water up into the attic and across to a place it can drain from.

It appears to be condensation right from the air. An AC operated in humid conditions can drip. Reduce the humidity, and it will also save energy, as well as reduce dripping.

Keep the AC vent closed, rather than admit outside air.
Reduce use of hot water and fix leaks.
Install a vapor barrier around house.

Also, gently, carefully, cleaning the evaporator fins, and spraying them with very dilute detergent (a few drops of detergent in a 1 liter spray bottle), can help water to cling to fins and drip down, rather than be forced out by air stream.

I have three other air conditioners in the same apartment and none of them exhibit this behavior. Can it really be that this one room is much more humid than the others?


That should have been in the question -- please edit it to include that info. 2. It could be more humid. Which room? 3. What does that have to do with cleaning and spraying evaporator?


I edited the question. The room is the master bedroom.
